# How to return only specific field in spring

Tags: java, json, spring

In the following code when I used projection it returns me the whole object of Group , But I want to get only `roleName` of class `Group` 
how can I do this?

**Projection: UserWithProfile**

```
@Projection(name="UserWithProfile",types=User.class)
public interface UserWithProfile extends UserGetters {
    UserPhoto getProfilePhoto();
}
```

**UserGetters**

```
public interface UserGetters{

    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getLogonEmail();
    boolean isEmailVerified();
    Group getGroup();
}
```

**User.class**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable, UserGetters {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Property.class)
    private Set<Property> favouriteProperty;

    @OneToOne
    private AcceptanceLetter acceptanceLetter;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String logonEmail;


    private String name;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private String password;


    private boolean emailVerified;

    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

    @OneToOne
    private Business business;

    private String address;

    private String postcode;

    private String phoneNo;

    private String passportNo;


    @Column(length=1000)
    private String description;


    @JsonIgnore
    private float meanRating;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user",targetEntity=UserPhoto.class)
    private UserPhoto profilePhoto;

    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
    Getter and setters... }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I tried  `@RestResource(exported = false)` its not worked but then I tried 
 `@JsonIgnore` it finally works :'D

Comment: Using Jackson’s @JsonIgnore is indeed the way to go. See the docs; https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections.hidden-data